# .jengine() not working in Java, but in R

Tags: java, r, jri

I took over an old project from an other person. Currently I'm trying to get this project to work.

Already in the beginning I get an Exception in:

```
R.parseAndEval(".jengine()");
```

It throws a `REngineEvalExcpetion: error during evaluation`.

If I use R in the R-Console, I needed to add a parameter `.jengine(start=TRUE)` to get the command `.jengine()` working. So I changed this line in Java accordingly, but I still get the same Exception.

I did a tutorial with R without calling `.jengine()` and using `Rengine` instead of `REngine` and at least somehow it worked and I could call R commands within Java.

I'm currently using R 3.3.3 and Java 1.8. I also don't know which versions have been used previously.

Answer (score 0):

"error during evaluation" just means that the R thread that is running the R script failed to run that command. But everything in the Java application is working properly. Is R that is failing.
R has to have the rJava library in order to run .jengine:

```
library(rJava)

.jinit(".")

.jengine(TRUE)
```